# Hide expected error from negative JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have this JUnit test which is testing negative case:

```
@Test
public void campaignTest() {

    Long campaignId = givenANotFoundCampaign();

    try {
        BonusSystemCampaign byId = bonusSystemCampaignService.getBonusSystemCampaign(campaignId, BonusSystemCampaign.class);

        assertNull(byId);
    } catch (Exception e){
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I execute it I get error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:12460/campaign/internal/campaigns/123
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

This error is correct but I would like to hide the error stack. How I can implement this?

Comment: It depends on how this is printed. If a logger is used, configure that logger (for your tests only) to not log anything. If some code is using `System.out` or `System.err` (possibly indirectly using `printStackTrace`), that's harder. You could try https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/standard-input-output/, but I don't know if capturing it will also cause it to not show up.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to check that this use case throws exception as expected you can try this :

- If you use **JUnit4** then add this annotation:
  `@Test(expected = FileNotFoundException.class)` .

It means that you expect this eception to pass the test

- If you use **JUnit5**:

  FileNotFoundException exception = assertThrows(FileNotFoundException.class, () -> {
  //Your process throws the exeption
  });

This way you can manipulate what to do with the variable of type `FileNotFoundException`